# Creating .docs file from .xml, .xslt and .docs template, using python

Tags: python, xml, xslt, docx

I am trying to create a .docx file, using the .docx template, .xml and .xslt file. I want to fill the placeholders in the .docx template file, with the data in the .xml file, and then generate a new word file, containing the data.

The template.docx file looks like this:

[image]

The data.xml file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <person>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <profession>dentist</profession>
        <city>Miami</city>
    </person>
    <person>
        <Name>Mia</Name>
        <profession>teacher</profession>
        <city>London</city>
    </person>
</root>
```

The parser.xslt file that I came up with looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/person">
      <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="profession"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output result.docs file should look like this:

[image]

My python code that I came up with looks like this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('data.xml')
xslt = ET.parse(r'parser.xslt')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
```

I don't know what the content of the .xslt file must be, in order to work, and how to create the result.docx

**Any kind of help will be appreciable**

Comment: A .docx file is actually a Zip file containing various XML documents. You need to read the Zip file, apply the XSLT to the appropriate XML file(s) within it and write a new .docx file. You will need to read your data.xml file within the XSLT in order to fill in the placeholders.

Comment: @Jelaby this is not very helpful...

Comment: Isn't it? I have to ask why you have chosen this approach, instead of using an existing library to edit the file (python-docx, for example)?

Comment: Since you are using Python in the first place and want to generate a native .docx file, I don't think XSLT is the right tool for the job. As the previous poster suggested, use a Python library to generate Word documents.

Comment: @Sebastien Okay so is there any library that replaces placeholder with a value ?